# Is there a specification-based testing framework for C# .Net 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, automated-tests

For example, [Reductio](http://reductiotest.org/) (for Java/Scala) and [QuickCheck](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/) (for Haskell).  The kind of framework I'm thinking of would provide "generators" for built-in data types and allow the programmer to define new generators.  Then, the programmer would define a test method that asserts some property, taking variables of the appropriate types as parameters.  The framework then generates a bunch of random data for the parameters, and runs hundreds of tests of that method.

For example, if I implemented a Vector class, and it had an add() method, I might want to check that my addition commutes.  So I would write something like (in pseudocode):

```
boolean testAddCommutes(Vector v1, Vector v2) {
    return v1.add(v2).equals(v2.add(v1));
}
```

I could run testAddCommutes() on two particular vectors to see if that addition commutes.  But instead of writing a few invocations of testAddCommutes, I write a procedure than generates arbitrary Vectors.  Given this, the framework can run testAddCommutes on hundreds of different inputs.

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 4):

There's FsCheck, a port from QuickCheck to F# and thus C#, although most of the doc seems to be for f#.
I've been exploring the ideas myself aswell. see : http://kilfour.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/testing-tool-tour-quicknet-preview/

Answer (score 1):

I may not understand correctly either, but [PEX](http://www.codeplex.com/Pex) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

to elaborate on my previous remark, the QN code to test the pseudo-code example would look something like this :

```
new TestRun(1, 1000)
    .AddTransition(new MetaTransition<Input<Vector, Vector>, Vector>
    {
        Name = "Vector Add ",
        Generator = DoubleVectorGenerator,
        Execute = input => input.paramOne.Add(input.paramTwo)
    }
    .RegisterProperty(
        (input, output) =>
            new QnProperty(
                "Is Communative",
                () => QnAssert.IsTrue(output == input.paramTwo.Add(input.paramOne) )
            )
        )
    )
    .Verify()
    .RethrowLastFailureifAny()
    .ReportPropertiesTested(new ConsoleReporter());
```

where DoubleVectorGenerator is a userdefined class supplying values of the type Input<Vector, Vector>.

Answer (score -1):

I might not understand you correctly but check this out...

http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx

Comment: Mocking is not what's being asked about